# Laravel multidimensional array get values

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, laravel-4

I have

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("557a9fd73b308828060025f0"),
   "account": {
     "email": "mail@gmail.com" 
  }
   "Phone": {
     "pri": {
         "number": "123456789",
         "type": "02"
     },
    "add": {
         "number": "456456456",
         "type": "03"
     }
  }
}
```

I use

```
$user = Sender::where('account.email', '=', 'mail@gmail.com')->first();  // WORKING
```

But I want search number : 123456789 in array Phone->pri

```
$user = Sender::where('Phone.pri.number', '=', '123456789')->first();  // NOT WORKING => RETURN EMPTY ARRAY
```

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: did you try `$user = Sender::where('Phone.pri.number', '=', '123456789')->first();`?

Comment: Sorry, this not working! Result return empty []

Comment: Instead of first try `get()`

Comment: @yogesh: tks but empty result

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
$user = Sender::where('Phone.pri.number', '=', '123456789')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user = Sender::where('Phone.pri.number', '=', 123456789)->first();
```

Search will consider the data type of search needle. If it is an integer you must not enclose it in ''